# FCM push notifications queuing up if browser is closed / Web-push

Tags: javascript, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

When browser is closed, every push notification that has been sent in the meantime is queued up, which leads to receiving hundreds of notifications when I open the browser for the first time next day. Is there a way of stopping push notifications queuing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to make use of [`time_to_live`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref):

> This parameter specifies how long (in seconds) the message should be kept in FCM storage if the device is offline. The maximum time to live supported is 4 weeks, and the default value is 4 weeks. For more information, see [Setting the lifespan of a message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl).

and set it to your desired time. Basically it determines until only when FCM would keep the message on the queue.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

- when you make the request to the push service you can include a `TTL` header (in seconds) for the notification, so that it expires if it is not delivered within that time
- you can use a `tag` for the notifications [when you display them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification) to hide the older notifications that belong to the same group (tag)

Answer (score 0):

For those using [web push](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-csharp) c# library the code reference to this is something like below:

```
    public void SendPushNotification(PushSubscription sub)
    {           

        var pushEndpoint = sub.EndPoint;
        var p256Dh = sub.P256dh;
        var auth = sub.Auth;
        const string subject = @"mailto:xyz@xyz.com";
        var publicKey = PushConfiguration.PublicKey; //configuration attribute coming from the web.config file
        var privateKey = PushConfiguration.PrivateKey; //configuration attribute coming from the web.config file
        var subscription = new PushSubscription(pushEndpoint, p256Dh, auth);
        var vapidDetails = new VapidDetails(subject, publicKey, privateKey);
        var options = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"TTL", 3}, {"vapidDetails", vapidDetails}};
        var myPayload = new NotificationData(){// my data};

        var webPushClient = new WebPushClient();
        try
        {
            webPushClient.SendNotification(subscription, myPayload , options);
        }
        catch (WebPushException exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Http STATUS code" + exception.StatusCode);
        }
    }
```